# Default option in select dropdown with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As another questions I use `ng-init` but something rare happen, when page load I have blank default option, when I clic and select another one blank option disapear, how can I drop this first option?

Code:

```
<select ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-init="selected = Catalogos[0]" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos">
</select>+
```

Controller:

```
   function cargarCatalogo() {
        apiService.get("../../api/Catalogos/", null,
            function (res) {
                console.log(res.data);
                $scope.Catalogos = res.data; 
            },
            errorCatalogo);
    }
```

Comment: I believe this is a scoping issue. It may be creating a different `selected` variable than your controller scope variable your ng-model is bound to. I will create a demo and double check.

Comment: I update my question with my scooping controller @mhodges

Comment: Ah, yes, that part of the code was very relevant. Check out my answer and I believe that will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about the timing of what is going on, the `ng-init` is being called prior to the ajax call returning. So, you're setting `selected = Catalogos[0]` which doesn't exist yet, so it is undefined. Then, when your ajax call returns and you set the $scope.Catalogos, it will load them into the select list, but still have `undefined` as the selected option. What you need to do is simply say `$scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];` in your ajax callback like so:

```
function cargarCatalogo() {
    apiService.get("../../api/Catalogos/", null,
        function (res) {
            console.log(res.data);
            $scope.Catalogos = res.data; 
            $scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];
        }, errorCatalogo);
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Gerardo No problem! Glad I could help =)